# MySQL return all data from conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I return all data if the dataset is like this?

```
id    |     status    |     timestamp
1     |       1       |    2019-04-29
2     |       1       |    2019-04-28
3     |       2       |    2019-04-05
4     |       3       |    2019-04-04
```

I would like to get all entries from the dataset with a query like this:

```
WHERE status = 1 AND timestamp = '2019-04-29'
WHERE status = 2 AND timestamp = '2019-04-05'
WHERE status = 3 AND timestamp = '2019-04-04'
```

the data that it should return should be

```
id    |     status    |     timestamp
1     |       1       |    2019-04-29
3     |       2       |    2019-04-05
4     |       3       |    2019-04-04
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `or`, but I think tuples make this simpler:

```
WHERE (status, timestamp) in ( (1, '2019-04-29'), (2, '2019-04-05'), (3, '2019-04-04'))
```

Comment: That should probably be "You can use `or`, but ..." :-)

Comment: *"but I think tuples make this simpler:"* if you wonder why you can't find tuple information in the MySQL manual to look why and how this works  in MySQL manual you would need to search on [Row Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/row-subqueries.html) or [Row Constructor Expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/row-constructor-optimization.html)

Comment: @GordonLinoff just a question

what if I wanted to do a comparison in the query?

like >= timestamp

Comment: @Daniel: Then you use `AND` and `OR` as mentioned by Gordon and shown in my answer.

Comment: @Daniel . . . Then you would need to use separate `OR` expressions, but that is not the question that you asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the alternative with mere `AND` and `OR` and appropriate parentheses:

```
WHERE (status = 1 AND timestamp = DATE '2019-04-29')
   OR (status = 2 AND timestamp = DATE '2019-04-05')
   OR (status = 3 AND timestamp = DATE '2019-04-04')
```

But I, too, prefer tuples as shown by Gordon :-)